# How do I create an alias in python?

Tags: python

I'm unsure if I'm using the right terminology, but I want to call my variable something else so that I don't need to type the entire variable every time I try to do something with it. For instance:

```
Shorten_This_Variable = "abc"
## I want to input code here that would represent Shorten_This_Variable as something like STV 
type(STV)
```

Comment: `STV = Shorten_This_Variable`?

Comment: Why? There's no benefits and logic in shortening variable names.

Comment: Variables cannot have aliases in Python. You can set another variable to the same value, but it will still be an independent variable.

Comment: Either choose good long, meaningful variable names or don't do that. You cannot do both.

Comment: Or use a different IDE, I suppose - PyCharm will offer to expand `STV` to `Shorten_This_Variable` when you type the former, so you'd just type `STV\t` or `STV\n` and get the full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is basically pointers, where a variable does not have a value (=memory allocated for data) but instead just points to some other memory (another variable). A much simplified explanation.

Pointers don't exist in Python so you can't do exactly what you want.

You can simulate pointers (kind of) by using mutable objects which are passed by reference.

For example:

```
Shorten_This_Variable = [ "abc" ]
STV = Shorten_This_Variable
STV[0] = "def"
```

Now both `Shorten_This_Variable` and `STV` point to the same list where the first and only element is `"def"`.

In the end, it's pretty pointless. Just choose better variable names.

Comment: At the start, it's pretty pointless..

Comment: Actually, an alias is not a pointer. Python variables already behave with reference semantics anyway. Also, nothing is ever passed by reference in python, indeed, passing by reference is essentially aliasing a variable in the caller with a parameter in a function, which python *does not ever support*

Comment: Thanks so much. Makes a lot more sense now